# Best practice for versioning .swf file

Tags: flash, git, apache-flex, version-control

Our team has one assets.swf file that holds all icons for Flex application.

What is the best practice for versioning .swf files?
Should we create .swf file for each developer?

Comment: Generally this site is used for giving answers to specific programming questions.  "Best practices" are rarely universal; so I don't think this question can be answered.  I'm not even sure I understand what information you're after.  What does creating a SWF for each developer have to do w/ versioning?

Comment: Interesting moderation.. You could change the title to "how to version flash files" and and maybe it won't get flagged.  Add in somewhere in the content "best practices appreciated but not required)"... expect them to show in people's answers.

Personally, I like good ol' SVN/GIT (and a policy of renaming with date stamp, with periodic cleanup).  Not flawless, but it works with small groups of designers and centralizes everyone.  The downside of course is if you have commits regularly, the merge process is manual by opening both and copying the changes so commit notes needed.

Locking can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some tools that can be used to create SWF graphics from text sources (SWFMill, HXSWFML and similar), FXG was an attempt to address this problem, but the majority of designers use source format which aren't possible to version, or is very difficult to incorporate into version control system.

The path of least resistance would be to allow to check in SWF binaries and to solve conflicts manually. Well... at least you know it's not your fault.

What you can do (I did this, but for other reasons): run the old and the new SWF files through `swfdump` and see the diff. Unfortunately, Flash compilers aren't designed to preserve the information exactly the same in binaries, if it didn't change between compiles, so some noise will get through. This, however, may give you a better idea of what has changed, if you are not sure of how to resolve the conflict (don't know what's inside the SWF). Technically, you could even check in the output of `swfdump` (it can be later assembled into SWF file it was parsed from), but it sounds like it just not worth the trouble, and is better addressed on administrative level, by, perhaps, requiring the people lock the file, if they are modifying it (and then run after them with a chainsaw demanding that they unlock it...) and so on. Well, as I've said before, not *really* good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Small static (ie which doesn't change often) resources (like icons) can be stored in Git.
It only is an issue when those resources are too big (because of their size or number), and then you would have to consider storing them in an external referential.

As for the SWF files (as described in "[Embedding assets from SWF files](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/07/25/embedding-assets-from-swf-files/)"), there are text files like any other sources, and can be accessed, branched, merged by all developers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But, AFAIK, .swf is not a text file, and thus it cannot be merged. My concern is that two developers may change .swf file at the same time, and then it will be impossible to merge their changes.

Comment: @IvanZamylin in that case, one swf per developer is not the solution. If there is a conflict when merging, you must pick the other version and reapply your modifications on top of it.